# Why does border: 5px dashed not come out as dashed in Firefox?

Tags: html, border, css

You can see the implementation here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wtcdt/

In FireFox on Mac, that circle is round/solid. I want it either dashed or dotted.

What makes it even weirder is that the same property (i.e. `border: 4px dashed #000`) works fine on an HR. So why does it not work when border-radius is involved?

This is so bizarre to me.

Comment: Details http://stackoverflow.com/a/26354776/2236219

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721), WebKit had a similar issue but it was [fixed in June](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9197).  [Here are all the other outstanding border-radius defects in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431176).

Comment: @marcamillion You have several options, not that you're necessarily going to like any of them: 1. write a patch for this issue and submit it to Mozilla; 2. Wait for someone else to fix it; 3. Use an image instead; 4. Use whatever you're using to fake it in IE instead; 5. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Funny...I never even thought about fixing it....but now that you mentioned it, I think I will look into it and see if I can help. Doubt it, but you never know!

Answer (score 0):

Your circle is too small. If you increase the height and width you will notice that the shape expands to a rounded-rectangle, the rounded edges remain solid but the lines become dashed.

Comment: Actually, that's not the case. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wtcdt/18/  Also, look at that in Chrome, then in Firefox. You will see a drastic difference. I want it to look in Firefox as it does in Chrome.

Comment: Very interesting. Looks like a bug. I'm using Firefox 3.0.19. You?

Comment: 3.6.13. It could be a bug, but I think it might be something more.

Comment: Well, it works as you intend it to in Safari and Chrome (Mac). It's not working in Firefox, be it Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Firefox bug. Typically you have to either make solid border or remove radius. But if both of the properties are important then you can replace the corner with image like this: http://eblog.foysalremon.com/dashed-border-radius-corners-rendered-as-solid-on-firefox-solved/