# How to make a smooth dashed border rotation animation like 'marching ants'

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, css-shapes

I'm working on a css animation that uses 'cogs and chains', but am unable to create a 'smooth' border rotation sequence.

You can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n56dn5b/14/) How (currently) I'm using a pseudo element to generate a 'rotation' effect. This is done by 'switching' between a dashed white and dashed gold colored border, making it seem like the 'border is rotating'.

**What I have**

```css
#one{
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */

}
#two{
  -webkit-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */

 position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:42px;
    width:80px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation{
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

/******************************************************************************/

.chain{
    height:70px;
    width:80%;
    border:5px dashed gold;
    border-radius:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:40px;
          -webkit-animation: switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}


@-webkit-keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder {
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}
@-moz-keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder{
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}
@-o-keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder {
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}
@keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder {  
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}



.chain:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:30px;
    width:100%;
    top:-5px;
    left:-5px;
    border:5px solid gold;
    z-index:-1;
          -webkit-animation: switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder {
  0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
@-moz-keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder{
  0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
@-o-keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder {
  0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
@keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder {  
    0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" style="width:50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25"/>
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M50 0, V15 M50 100, V85 M0 50, H15 M100 50, H85"/>
    </defs>    
    <use xlink:href="#c"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"/>
</svg>

<svg id="two" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <use xlink:href="#one"/>    
</svg>
<div class="chain"></div>
```

So, the lower section of the snippet, you can see how I've generated the 'rotating chain effect' through using keyframes.

---

**What I would like**

My overall wish would be to generate something like:

*Think of a cross section of a conveyor belt, and how the 'gears at the end drive the belt'. I'm trying to reproduce that. (i.e. the dashed border's gold bits should be within the troughs of the gear, and 'be pulled' by it)*

```css
#one{
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
border:5px dashed gold;
  border-radius:50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation{
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" style="width:50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25"/>
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M50 0, V15 M50 100, V85 M0 50, H15 M100 50, H85"/>
    </defs>    
    <use xlink:href="#c"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"/>
</svg>
```

but with the gold dashes to fit within the gear's troughs, as well as being 80% width of the screen (if that makes sense).

In the end, I would like to generate something like this image portrays:

[image]

See how i want the chain to 'rotate'?

---

**My Current Issues**

- Since the animation is 'hacked' via the use of a pseudo element, I've found it quite hard to actually sync the rotation of this 'chain'.
- I'm still learning keyframe animation, so I'm sure that isn't the best method for this
- Again, svg is a new concept for me, so bear with my reluctance to use it (hence why I'm using css for the 'chain')
- In the end, I want to 'make it look like' the gear is turning the chain, but right now they look like completely (and badly done) separate element animations

---

Comment: You can create by svg animation. 
you can visit this demo: http://codepen.io/nathandana/pen/hsLli

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Cog and chain animation :

I totaly refactored the code (*CSS* and *HTML*), it is now :

- shorter (especialy the css)
- simpler
- more realistic: corrected the synchronisation issue bteween the chain and the cogs and added a missing cog on the right because your chain seemed to be floating in the air :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/MYGVON)**

The approach is the same, animating the rotation angle for the cogs and `dash-offset` for the chain path. I tweaked the timing between both animations to make it look as if the cogs are pulling the chain.

### Browser support :

As IE [doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility) the svg animate element I also made this version of the animation with the [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) library that also supports IE9 and over (tested in IE9 with [crossbrowsertesting](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/test-center)).

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/emroGg)** with IE support

```js
var cont   = new Snap('#svg'),
    chain  = cont.select('#chain'),
    cogAcw = cont.select('#cog_acw'),
    cogCw  = cont.select('#cog_cw'),
    speed  = 500;  // Lower this number to make the animation faster

function infChain(el) {
    var len = el.getTotalLength();
    el.attr({"stroke-dasharray": len/62,"stroke-dashoffset": 0});
    el.animate({"stroke-dashoffset": -len/31}, speed, mina.linear, infChain.bind(null, el));
}
function rotateAcw(el) {
    el.transform('r22.5,20,20');
    el.animate({ transform: 'r-22.5,20,20' }, speed, mina.linear, rotateAcw.bind( null, el));
}
function rotateCw(el) {
    el.transform('r0,20,20');
    el.animate({ transform: 'r45,20,20' }, speed, mina.linear, rotateCw.bind( null, el));
}
infChain(chain);
rotateAcw(cogAcw);
rotateCw(cogCw);
```

```css
svg {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://thisisa.simple-url.com/js/snapsvg.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 30">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="20" cy="20" r="4" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="4" />
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="2" d="M20 13 V16 M27 20 H24 M20 27 V24 M13 20 H16" />
        <g id="cog_acw">
            <use xlink:href="#c" /><use xlink:href="#d" />
            <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)" />
        </g>  
        <g id="cog_cw">
            <use xlink:href="#c" /><use xlink:href="#d" />
            <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)" />
        </g>  
    </defs>
    <path id="chain" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" 
    d="M21.3 13.5 H20 C11.4 13.5 11.4 26.5 20 26.5 H80 C89.4 26.5 89.4 13.5 80.8 13.5z" />
    <use  xlink:href="#cog_acw" />
    <use  transform="translate(60.5 0), rotate(19,20,20)" xlink:href="#cog_acw" />
    <use  transform="translate(-4.5 -4.5),scale(.8), rotate(0,20,20)" xlink:href="#cog_cw" />    
</svg>
```

---

```css
svg{width:100%;}
#chain_st{
  -webkit-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@-moz-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@-o-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 30">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c" cx="20" cy="20" r="4" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="4"/>
    <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="2" d="M20 13 V16 M27 20 H24 M20 27 V24 M13 20 H16"/>
    <g id="cog">
      <use xlink:href="#c"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0,-7), scale(0.8), rotate(22.5 8 8)">
    <use xlink:href="#cog">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="-22.5 20 20" to="337.5 20 20" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </use>
  </g>
  <path id="chain_st" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="2.6 2.45" d="M21.3 13.5 H20 C11.4 13.5 11.4 26.5 20 26.5 H80 C89 26.5 89 13.5 80.8 13.5z" />
  <use class="rot" xlink:href="#cog">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate"from="22.5 20 20" to="-337.5 20 20" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <g transform="translate(60.3 0)">
    <use class="" xlink:href="#cog">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="22.5 20 20" to="-337.5 20 20" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

**Original answer :**

You could use an other svg dashed path and animate the dash-offset property with a keyframe animation.

This can and should be simplified/tweaked for a "real world" use :

- all elements can be contained into one `<svg>` tag (this would make it simpler and both cogs + chain could resize together)
- The sync between the chain and the cog isn't perfect and speed/size of chain needs to be tweaked.

```css
#one {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
#two {
  -webkit-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 42px;
  width: 80px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
/******************************************************************************/

#chain {
  width: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 35px;
}
.chain_st {
  stroke-dasharray: 1.5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10;
  -webkit-animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
  animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" style="width:50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25" />
    <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M50 0, V15 M50 100, V85 M0 50, H15 M100 50, H85" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#c" />
  <use xlink:href="#d" />
  <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)" />
</svg>

<svg id="two" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="#one" />
</svg>
<svg id="chain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 70 10">
  <path class="chain_st" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" d="M60 1 Q65 1 65 5 Q65 9 60 9 H6 Q1 9 1 5 Q1 1 6 1z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: FWIW, the non-IE version works a lot better on Safari than does the IE version.

Answer (score 29):

How about this approach?  I'm using SVG for both the gears and the conveyor.  The gears rotate as per your example, but I am using `stroke-dasharray` and animating `stroke-dash-offset` to make the conveyor belt move.

It took a bit of fiddling to get the conveyor length and dash timing right, which you would need to tweak again if you change the gear size or conveyor length.

```css
#one{
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */

}
#two{
  -webkit-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 4s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */

 position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:42px;
    width:80px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation{
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}


/******************************************************************************/

#chain
{
  -webkit-animation: conveyor 0.5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    conveyor 0.5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      conveyor 0.5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         conveyor 0.5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}


@-webkit-keyframes conveyor {
    0%   { stroke-dashoffset: -9; }
    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 20.06; }
}
@-moz-keyframes conveyor {
    0%   { stroke-dashoffset: -9; }
    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 20.06; }
}
@-o-keyframes conveyor {
    0%   { stroke-dashoffset: -9; }
    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 20.06; }
}
@keyframes conveyor {  
    0%   { stroke-dashoffset: -9; }
    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 20.06; }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 800 100">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="0" cy="0" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25"/>
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M0,-50 v15 M0,50 v-15 M-50,0 h15 M50,0 h-15"/>

        <g id="gear">
          <use xlink:href="#c"/>
          <use xlink:href="#d"/>
          <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45)"/>
        </g>
    </defs>
  
  <rect id="chain2"
          x="43" y="23" width="598" height="74" rx="37"
          stroke="gold" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>

    <g transform="translate(27,27) scale(0.5)">
      <g id="one">
        <use xlink:href="#gear"/>
      </g>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(80,60) scale(0.8)">
      <g id="two">
        <use xlink:href="#gear"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  
  <rect id="chain"
          x="43" y="23" width="598" height="74" rx="37"
          stroke="gold" stroke-width="5" fill="none"
          stroke-dasharray="14 15.06"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Very similar to web-tiki's I know, but answered independently in parallel.

Comment: If you want it to look more chain-like, you could probably add a second thinner yellow path in the background of the dashed path. This line will look like links between the parts of the chain... - I did an Edit just to show what I mean, you don't need to accept

Comment: Gears are now fixed in FF.

Comment: I can confirm that this snippet now works perfectly in FF35 and Chrome 40. However, it is a static image in IE11.

Comment: IE does not support CSS3 animation when applied to SVG elements.

Answer (score 18):

**Note:** I have remade the whole animation in box-shadow, because using dashed borders doesn't have consistent output on all the browsers.

### Working

**.. and Works cross-browser.**
*FF 5+, GC 4+, IE9+, Safari 4+, Opera 12.1+*

You can try this using box-shadow :

- To make the gears teeth, use box-shadow with negative spread radius. The size of my gear was `50px` for example, so to get round `box-shadow` with `d=8px`, I used `-46px` as spread radius.
- I positioned the teeth using coordinate geo, and only used 8 teeth to simplify.
- Now for the straight conveyor, we need to know the distance between the teeth. We get that by the following :
- `2*pi*(gear radius) / no. of teeth` = `(pi * r) / 4`
  **Mine** = `(55 * 3.1415) / 4 = 43` (approx.)
  I took the radius as 55 because the teeth have 4px radius and are lying 1px away from gear circumference.
- For aligning the top and bottom straight conveyors, they need to be translated by any multiple of their distance. For my gear, I translate them by 43px.

### The Scaffolding

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hpLqmfs8/)**

```css
body {
    background: rgba(25,80,175, 0.4);
}
.rect {
    height: 116px;
    width: 401px;
    border-radius: 58px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rect:before, .rect:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 46px; /*50-half width*/
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 43px 0 0 0 white, 86px 0 0 0 white, 129px 0 0 0 white, 172px 0 0 0 white, 215px 0 0 0 white, 258px 0 0 0 white, 301px 0 0 0 white;
    -webkit-animation: apple 0.3s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: apple 0.3s linear infinite;
    animation: apple 0.3s linear infinite;
}
.rect:before {
    top: 0px;
}
.rect:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes apple {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes apple {
    0% {-moz-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@keyframes apple {
    0% {transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
.left, .right {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: 0 55px 0 -46px white, 55px 0 0 -46px white, 0 -55px 0 -46px white, -55px 0 0 -46px white,
        39px 39px 0 -46px white, -39px -39px 0 -46px white, 39px -39px 0 -46px white, -39px 39px 0 -46px white;
    -webkit-animation: mango 2.4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: mango 2.4s linear infinite;
    animation: mango 2.4s linear infinite;
}
.left {
    top: -108px;
    left: 0px;
}
.right {
    top: -208px;
    left: 301px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mango {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes mango {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@keyframes mango {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

---

### Final version

**... with gears.** The chain currently is <strike>dotted</strike> dashed!

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4jemr2uo/)**

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}
.rect {
    height: 120px;
    width: 401px;
    border-radius: 58px;
    position: relative;
}

.rect:before, .rect:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px; /*50-half width*/
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 43px 0 0 0 gold, 86px 0 0 0 gold, 129px 0 0 0 gold, 172px 0 0 0 gold, 215px 0 0 0 gold, 258px 0 0 0 gold, 301px 0 0 0 gold, 344px 0 0 0 gold; /*keep adding 43 to x-axis*/
    -webkit-animation: apple 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: apple 0.6s linear infinite;
    animation: apple 0.6s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rect:before {
    top: 0px;
}
.rect:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes apple {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes apple {
    0% {-moz-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@keyframes apple {
    0% {transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
.left, .right {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: mango 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: mango 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: mango 4.8s linear infinite;
}
.left {
    top: -110px;
    left: 0px;
}
.right {
    top: -210px;
    left: 344px;
}
.left:before, .left:after, .right:before, .right:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gold;
}
.left:before, .right:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold, 0 100px 0 0 gold;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
.left:after, .right:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
    left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 gold, 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mango {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes mango {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@keyframes mango {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
.cover {
    height: 104px;
    width: 446px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    top: -312px;
    left; -2px;
    
}
.gear, .gear2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: dimgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: gear 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: gear 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: gear 4.8s linear infinite;
}
.gear {
    top: -414px;
  
}
.gear2 {
    top: -514px;
    left: 345px;
}
.gear:before, .gear:after, .gear2:before, .gear2:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: dimgray;
    
}
.gear:before, .gear2:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, 0 100px 0 0 dimgray;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
.gear:after, .gear2:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
    left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 dimgray, 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray;
}
@-webkit-keyframes gear {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-337.5deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes gear {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-337.5deg);}
}
@keyframes gear {
    0% {transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-337.5deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="gear"></div>
<div class="gear2"></div>
```

## Final version (Rounded cog-teeth)

```css
.rect {
    height: 120px;
    width: 401px;
    border-radius: 58px;
    position: relative;
}
.rect:before, .rect:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px; /*50-half width*/
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    box-shadow: 43px 0 0 0 gold, 86px 0 0 0 gold, 129px 0 0 0 gold, 172px 0 0 0 gold, 215px 0 0 0 gold, 258px 0 0 0 gold, 301px 0 0 0 gold, 344px 0 0 0 gold; /*keep adding 43 to x-axis*/
    -webkit-animation: translate 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: translate 0.6s linear infinite;
    animation: translate 0.6s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rect:before {top: 0px;}
.rect:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes translate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes translate {
    0% {-moz-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@keyframes translate {
    0% {transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
.left, .right {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
}
.left {
    top: -110px; left: 0px;
}
.right {
    top: -210px; left: 344px;
}
.left:before, .left:after, .right:before, .right:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: gold;
}
.left:before, .right:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold, 0 100px 0 0 gold;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
.left:after, .right:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
    left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 gold, 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
.cover {
    height: 104px;
    width: 446px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    top: -312px;
    left; -2px;
}
.gear, .gear2, .gear3 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 35px dimgray, inset 0 0 0px 40px #444;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.gear {top: -414px;}
.gear2 {top: -514px; left: 345px;}
.gear:before, .gear:after, .gear2:before, .gear2:after,  .gear3:before, .gear3:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background: dimgray;
}
.gear:before, .gear2:before, .gear3:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, 0 100px 0 0 dimgray;
    top: -10px; left: 40px;
}
.gear:after, .gear2:after, .gear3:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px; left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 dimgray, 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray;
}
.gear3 {
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    top: -504px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="gear"></div>
<div class="gear2"></div>
<div class="gear3"></div>
```

**[FIDDLE - ROUNDED TEETH](http://jsfiddle.net/gdh6wa7w/)**

---

**NOTE :** To increase the speed of animation, you simply have to decrease the animation duration of each element **proportionally**.

[Fiddle (fast)](http://jsfiddle.net/t80d5oy1/)

Answer (score 15):

Here is a different method on how to achieve cog animation using CSS. This method has been tested in IE11, IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari.

- Two circular elements for gears/cogs with inset `box-shadow` to produce the inner circle. The teeth are produced by child elements (normal + pseudo) which are rotated around the axis.
- The curved part of the belt is achieved using the same technique as the spokes of the gear and are positioned such that they are always in between the teeth.
- One rectangular container element whose top and bottom borders are mimicked using linear-gradient. The background of this element (other than the gradient on top and bottom) is a solid color which is sort of a drawback. This solid color is used to hide half of the circular element on either side.
- The animation is achieved in two ways (a) constantly rotating both the circular elements and (b) constantly changing the background-position of the gradient backgrounds.

```css
.chain {
    margin: 45px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 310px;
    position: relative;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
    background-size: 41px 5px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 20px 0px, 20px 95px;
    -webkit-animation: bgPos 1s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: bgPos 1s infinite linear;
    animation: bgPos 1s infinite linear;
}
.belt, .belt-after, .belt .spokes, .belt .spokes:before, .belt .spokes:after, .belt-after .spokes, .belt-after .spokes:before, .belt-after .spokes:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    height: 90px;
    width:15px;
    top: 0px;
    border-top: 5px solid gold;
    border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
    z-index: -1;
}
.belt, .belt-after {
    -webkit-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
    animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
}
.belt .spokes, .belt-after .spokes {
    top: -5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.belt .spokes:before, .belt-after .spokes:before {
    top: -5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.belt .spokes:after, .belt-after .spokes:after {
    top: -5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.belt {
    left: -16px;
}
.belt-after {
    right: -16px;
}
.gear {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
    animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px gray;
    z-index: 4;
}
.gear:before, .gear .spokes, .gear .spokes:before, .gear .spokes:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    height: 88px;
    width:15px;
    top: -5px;
    border-top: 6px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 6px solid gray;
}
.gear:before {
    left: 37px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
    transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}
.gear .spokes {
    left: 37px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
    transform: rotate(67.5deg);
}
.gear .spokes:before {
    top: -6px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.gear .spokes:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.chain .belt + .gear {
    left:-52px;
}
.chain .belt-after + .gear {
    right: -52.5px;
}
.gear-small {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -92px;
    top: -20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: borderAnim 6s infinite linear reverse;
    -moz-animation: borderAnim 6s infinite linear reverse;
    animation: borderAnim 6s infinite linear reverse;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px gray;
    z-index: -2;
}
.gear-small:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    left: 21px;
    top: -3px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 10px;
    border-top:4px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
}
.gear-small .spokes, .gear-small .spokes:before, .gear-small .spokes:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    left: 21px;
    top: -3px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 10px;
    border-top:4px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
}
.gear-small .spokes {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.gear-small .spokes:before {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.gear-small .spokes:after {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderAnim {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes borderAnim {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@keyframes borderAnim {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgPos {
    0% {
        background-position: 20px 0px, -20px 95px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -20px 0px, 20px 95px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bgPos {
    0% {
        background-position: 20px 0px, -20px 95px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -20px 0px, 20px 95px;
    }
}
@keyframes bgPos {
    0% {
        background-position: 20px 0px, -20px 95px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -20px 0px, 20px 95px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="chain">
    <div class="gear-small">
        <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="belt">
        <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gear">
        <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="belt-after">
        <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gear">
        <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bonus:** Here is the whole animation with an on/off switch :) Click (pull) the chain handle to switch the animation on or off.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.chain {
  margin: 45px 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
  background-size: 41px 5px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 20px 0px, 20px 95px;
  -webkit-animation: bgPos 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: bgPos 1s infinite linear;
  animation: bgPos 1s infinite linear;
}
.belt,
.belt-after,
.belt .spokes,
.belt .spokes:before,
.belt .spokes:after,
.belt-after .spokes,
.belt-after .spokes:before,
.belt-after .spokes:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  border-top: 5px solid gold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
  z-index: -1;
}
.belt,
.belt-after {
  -webkit-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
  animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
}
.belt .spokes,
.belt-after .spokes {
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.belt .spokes:before,
.belt .spokes:after,
.belt-after .spokes,
.belt-after .spokes:before,
.belt-after .spokes:after {
  content: '';
}
.belt .spokes:before,
.belt-after .spokes:before {
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.belt .spokes:after,
.belt-after .spokes:after {
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.belt {
  left: -16px;
}
.belt-after {
  right: -16px;
}
.gear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
  animation: borderAnim 8s infinite linear;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px gray, inset 0px 0px 0px 40px white, inset 0px 0px 0px 50px tomato;
  z-index: 4;
}
.gear:before,
.gear .spokes,
.gear .spokes:before,
.gear .spokes:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 88px;
  width: 15px;
  top: -5px;
  border-top: 6px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 6px solid gray;
}
.gear:before {
  left: 37px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}
.gear .spokes {
  left: 37px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  transform: rotate(67.5deg);
}
.gear .spokes:before {
  top: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.gear .spokes:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.chain .belt + .gear {
  left: -52px;
}
.chain .belt-after + .gear {
  right: -52.5px;
}
.gear-small {
  position: absolute;
  left: -91px;
  top: -20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: borderAnim 8s 0.4s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: borderAnim 6s infinite linear;
  animation: borderAnim 6s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px gray;
  z-index: -2;
}
.gear-small:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 21px;
  top: -3px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 10px;
  border-top: 4px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
}
.gear-small .spokes,
.gear-small .spokes:before,
.gear-small .spokes:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 21px;
  top: -3px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 10px;
  border-top: 4px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
}
.gear-small .spokes {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.gear-small .spokes:before {
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.gear-small .spokes:after {
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgPos {
  0% {
    background-position: 20px 0px, -20px 95px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -20px 0px, 20px 95px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes bgPos {
  0% {
    background-position: 20px 0px, -20px 95px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -20px 0px, 20px 95px;
  }
}
@keyframes bgPos {
  0% {
    background-position: 20px 0px, -20px 95px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -20px 0px, 20px 95px;
  }
}
#pull-switch {
  display: none;
  /* no need to display checkbox */
}
#switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 77px;
  top: 50px;
  border-right: 2px dotted tomato;
  height: 200px;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
}
#handle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /* left: width of chain div (15px) + half of border (1px) - radius of handle (8px)*/
  left: 8px;
  bottom: 0%;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer
}
#pull-switch:checked + #switch > #handle {
  background-color: seagreen;
}
#pull-switch:checked + #switch {
  height: 225px;
  border-color: seagreen;
}
#pull-switch ~ .chain .gear-small,
#pull-switch ~ .chain .belt,
#pull-switch ~ .chain .belt-after,
#pull-switch ~ .chain .gear,
#pull-switch ~ .chain {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain .gear-small,
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain .belt,
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain .belt-after,
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain .gear,
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain .belt + .gear,
#pull-switch:checked ~ .chain .belt-after + .gear {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px gray, inset 0px 0px 0px 40px white, inset 0px 0px 0px 50px seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="pull-switch" />
  <div id="switch">
    <label for="pull-switch" id="handle"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="chain">
    <div class="gear-small">
      <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="belt">
      <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gear">
      <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="belt-after">
      <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gear">
      <div class="spokes"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Original Answer:** (Doesn't work on Firefox due to dashed border bug and dashes are more closer in IE making it look ugly).

You could achieve the border rotation animation by using a combination of the following:

- Two circular elements (using `border-radius: 50%`) with dashed border on either side to form the curved part of the border.
- One rectangular container element whose top and bottom borders are mimicked using `linear-gradient`. The background of this element (other than the gradient on top and bottom) is a solid color which is sort of a drawback. This solid color is used to hide half of the circular element on either side.
- The animation is achieved in two ways (a) constantly rotating both the circular elements and (b) constantly changing the `background-position` of the gradient backgrounds.
- The cogs are also circular elements where the spokes are made with dashed borders and the solid inner part is generated using an inset `box-shadow`. The cog is rotated in such a way that the chain's border is always in between the cog's border.

```css
.chain {
  margin: 45px auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, transparent 50%), white;
  background-size: 30px 5px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 5px 95px;
  -webkit-animation: bgPos 4s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: bgPos 4s infinite linear;
  animation: bgPos 4s infinite linear;
}
.chain .before,
.chain .after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px dashed gold;
  -webkit-animation: borderAnim 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: borderAnim 2s infinite linear;
  animation: borderAnim 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: -2;
}
.chain .before {
  left: -45px;
}
.chain .after {
  right: -45px;
}
.chain .gear {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px dashed gray;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(16deg);
  transform: rotate(16deg);
  -webkit-animation: gearAnim 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: gearAnim 2s infinite linear;
  animation: gearAnim 2s infinite linear;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px gray;
  z-index: 4;
}
.chain .before + .gear {
  left: -45px;
}
.chain .after + .gear {
  right: -45px;
}
.gear-small {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -95px;
  top: -23px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px dashed gray;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(16deg);
  transform: rotate(16deg);
  -webkit-animation: gearAnim 6s infinite linear reverse;
  -moz-animation: gearAnim 6s infinite linear reverse;
  animation: gearAnim 6s infinite linear reverse;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px gray;
  z-index: -2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgPos {
  0% {
    background-position: 610px 0px, 0px 95px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 600px 95px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes bgPos {
  0% {
    background-position: 610px 0px, 0px 95px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 600px 95px;
  }
}
@keyframes bgPos {
  0% {
    background-position: 610px 0px, 0px 95px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 600px 95px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gearAnim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(376deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes gearrAnim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(376deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(16deg);
  }
}
@keyframes gearAnim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(376deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(16deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chain">
  <div class="gear-small"></div>
  <div class="before"></div>
  <div class="gear"></div>
  <div class="after"></div>
  <div class="gear"></div>
</div>
```

> Last but not least, I would still recommend using the SVG approach for this because beyond a certain point such animations with CSS would become very messy :)

Comment: Hey its nice but not working on Chromium V.38.0.2125.111

Comment: @ThePragmatick: Yep, there was wrong `-webkit-` prefix in the linear-gradient line and since the angles were different it was causing an issue. Now addressed :)

Comment: Nice! Now its working. But as you said, SVG is the best option here. Dashed borders are becoming messy.

Comment: how can left and right border looks running? it doesn't look running I think

Comment: @JeanGkol: I think you are may be affected by this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756049/why-does-border-5px-dashed-not-come-out-as-dashed-in-firefox).

Comment: well, I'm not feeling I'm an expert with this. that's what makes me ask you. I see your links and I get your point. thanks

Comment: @JeanGkol: Not a problem mate. I couldn't check it out because I am using  an old FF version and it does have the issue (the circular bits look solid). Will add a note in answer to help future readers.

Comment: I see the left and right border in chrome and it really works :D

Answer (score 4):

You could try and edit cog so it fits better instead of tweaking div border to fall into place on cog. Its easier to manipulate graphics than css.

And from there maybe to split chain animation in three or four parts to make it more robust.

Then you could tweak speeds of cog and chain to match, hide a half of chain, add onto it div only with top and bottom border and do the same but opposite on other end. (using cliping, position and z-index).

Something like this:

[image: xhtml]

In theory at least, that would be my approach (not to mention that I would use JS instead of this workflow).

Answer (score 3):

## Using Canvas

The shapes (cog and chain) and the marching ants animation effect (dashed border) can also be achieved by using a Canvas drawing. The browser support for Canvas is [quite good](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas).

While Canvas has the disadvantage of being raster based (as opposed to SVG, which is shape based), it is not a big problem as long as the canvas is not scaled too much. Canvas is expected to be better when handling a large number of objects and real-time animations. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh552482.aspx) is an interesting article from the MSDN on when to use Canvas or SVG.

---

### Construction of Shapes

The following are the key parts/shapes involved in this animation:

- Chain
- Left Cog
- Right Cog
- Top Cog

**Chain**: The chain is created by drawing two horizontal lines (using the `lineTo` commands) that are connected at either end by semicircles (drawn using the `arc` command). The dashed border effect is achieved by using `setLineDash` method for the stroke. `setLineDash` method takes two parameters where the first represents the length of the dash and the second represents the gap between dashes.

Below snippet shows the minimal code required to create the chain:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var chain = {
    offset: 0,
    paint: function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
      ctx.lineTo(533, 50);
      ctx.arc(533, 100, 50, (Math.PI * 1.5), (Math.PI * 0.5), false);
      ctx.lineTo(75, 150);
      ctx.arc(75, 100, 50, (Math.PI * 0.5), (Math.PI * 1.5), false);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'transparent';
      ctx.setLineDash([12, 14.16]);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = this.offset;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };

  chain.paint();
}
```

```css
/* CSS needed only for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
canvas {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='650' height='300'></canvas>
```

**Cogs**: All the three cogs (left, right and top) are achieved using the same commands and the only difference is their positioning on screen (and radius for the top one).

The spokes or teeth of the cogs are created by using the `arc` command (as done for the semicircles of the chain), and use the same radius. Their `lineDashoffset` is adjusted such that they occupy the exact space left between the dashes of the chain.

The body of the cogs are made up of two circles with the outer one having a bigger radius than the inner. The [`evenodd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule) fill parameter is used to set the background color (`tan` in this example) only on the outer circle and leaving the inner one transparent.

Below snippet shows the minimal code required to create the cogs:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var cog = {
    paint: function(x, y, r, offset) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.setLineDash([12, 14.16]);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = offset;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'tan';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, (r - 2), 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.arc(x, y, (r / 2.5), 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'tan';
      ctx.fill('evenodd');
    }
  };

  function paint() {
    var cog_radius = 50;
    var cog_t_x = 30,
      cog_t_y = 40,
      cog_t_offset = 20.5,
      cog_l_x = 75,
      cog_l_y = 100,
      cog_l_offset = 24.25,
      cog_r_x = 533,
      cog_r_offset = 11.25;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    cog.paint(cog_t_x, cog_t_y, (cog_radius / 2), cog_t_offset);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    cog.paint(cog_l_x, cog_l_y, cog_radius, cog_l_offset);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    cog.paint(cog_r_x, cog_l_y, cog_radius, cog_r_offset);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  paint();

}
```

```css
/* CSS needed only for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
canvas {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='650' height='300'></canvas>
```

---

### Animation

The animation is achieved by shifting the `lineDashOffset` of the strokes in each frame of the animation. The animation itself is triggered using the [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) method which calls the paint function (passed as an argument) at regular intervals. The rate of callback is generally 60 times per second (quoting MDN). Shifting the offset during every repaint of the canvas gives the appearance of it being animated.

The animation can be stopped at any point of time by calling the [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) method. This can be done either based on some user interaction (like click, hover etc), or based on a time-out.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var anim, onState = false,
    counter = 0;
  var chain = {
    offset: 0,
    paint: function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
      ctx.lineTo(533, 50);
      ctx.arc(533, 100, 50, (Math.PI * 1.5), (Math.PI * 0.5), false);
      ctx.lineTo(75, 150);
      ctx.arc(75, 100, 50, (Math.PI * 0.5), (Math.PI * 1.5), false);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'transparent';
      ctx.setLineDash([12, 14.16]);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = this.offset;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };

  function paint(type) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    chain.offset += (6.54 / 10);
    ctx.save();
    chain.paint();
    ctx.restore();
    if (type) {
      anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        paint(type);
      })
    }
  }
  paint(true);
}
```

```css
/* CSS needed only for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
canvas {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='650' height='300'></canvas>
```

---

### Complete Picture

Putting all the parts together, the below snippet provides the complete picture of the chain and cogs along with the animation:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var anim, onState = false,
    counter = 0;
  var cog_radius = 50;
  var cog_t_x = 30,
    cog_t_y = 40,
    cog_t_offset = 20.5,
    cog_l_x = 75,
    cog_l_y = 100,
    cog_l_offset = 24.25,
    cog_r_x = 533,
    cog_r_offset = 11.25;
  var chain = {
    offset: 0,
    paint: function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
      ctx.lineTo(533, 50);
      ctx.arc(533, 100, 50, (Math.PI * 1.5), (Math.PI * 0.5), false);
      ctx.lineTo(75, 150);
      ctx.arc(75, 100, 50, (Math.PI * 0.5), (Math.PI * 1.5), false);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'transparent';
      ctx.setLineDash([12, 14.16]);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = this.offset;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };
  var cog = {
    paint: function(x, y, r, offset) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.setLineDash([12, 14.16]);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = offset;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'tan';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, (r - 2), 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.arc(x, y, (r / 2.5), 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'tan';
      ctx.fill('evenodd');
    }
  };

  function paint(type) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    chain.offset += (6.54 / 10);
    cog_l_offset -= (6.54 / 10);
    cog_r_offset -= (6.54 / 10);
    cog_t_offset += (6.54 / 10);
    ctx.save();
    cog.paint(cog_t_x, cog_t_y, (cog_radius / 2), cog_t_offset);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    chain.paint();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    cog.paint(cog_l_x, cog_l_y, cog_radius, cog_l_offset);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.save();
    cog.paint(cog_r_x, cog_l_y, cog_radius, cog_r_offset);
    ctx.restore();
    if (type) {
      anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        paint(type);
      })
    }
  }
  paint(true);
}
```

```css
/* CSS needed only for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
canvas {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='650' height='300'></canvas>
```

---

### User Interaction

As mentioned earlier, user interaction can also be added using event listeners (`addEventListener`). If the action needs to be triggered by user action on a specific shape or section of the canvas then the `pointInPath` method can be used to verify if the point is within the required section of the canvas.

[Here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/details/rVwgPE/) is the link to a CodePen demo which has these user interactions (and some other extra stuff) also added.

<sup>**Note:** Explanation on how to add user interactions etc is beyond the scope of this particular answer. However, if you need any help you can find me in [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-and-designs).</sup>