# How to create the transparent circle with cut inside?

Tags: html, css

Can we create transparent circle with cut inside with css and html?
I have attached the image for the clarification

[image: transparent circle with cut inside]

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `:after` pseudo-element

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 7%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG might be an option.

See this excellent [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087463/dotted-dashed-circle-shapes-using-css-not-rendering-right-in-chrome/30093139#30093139)

[**More complex Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/reVEwy)

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
.dashed {
  stroke-dasharray: 75, 10;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="50" class="dashed" />
</svg>
```