# Dashed border with applied border-radius have wrong length in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have noticed that applying a dashed border on a div together with `border-radius` creates "dashed" with wrong length.

Please look at image below near the corners, the problem appears only on Firefox 44 and 46 and looks fine on Chrome 49.

[image]

It looks like  [a bug in FF](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1257447). I am aware that border-radius is problematic on [FF](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431176), but I would like to know if there is a work around for that.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#target {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 10px dashed purple;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Dashed borders rendering has had problems for a long time now (initially FF didn't even render them with 50% border-radius). It might be better to use SVG like [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087463/dotted-dashed-circle-shapes-using-css-not-rendering-right-in-chrome/30093139#30093139) (*The shape there is different and hence I don't think this is a exact dupe.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the css property of `border` you can not achieve it.

Css rendering is browser specific and I think the only work around is to **use image**.